# Confluence Macro Plugin is shown as installed but Macro does not work

Tags: java, confluence

i am trying to programm a Plugin in Confluence for my Company, i used this tutorial: https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/tutorials/macro-tutorials-for-confluence/creating-a-new-confluence-macro and did everything how the tutorial told me to, but the Macro does not work, it is shown as a unkown Macro in Confluence, when i try to use it. But the Plugin itself is shown as Installed and activated.

I programm on Eclipse Luna and use Confluence 5.9..2 running locally over the Atlas-run option.

Here is my Source Code:

Main File:

```
package com.company.confluence.plugin;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.XhtmlException;
import com.atlassian.confluence.xhtml.api.MacroDefinition;
import com.atlassian.confluence.xhtml.api.MacroDefinitionHandler;
import java.util.Map;
import com.atlassian.confluence.xhtml.api.XhtmlContent;
import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.ConversionContext;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.Macro;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.MacroExecutionException;
public class MyConfluenceMacro implements Macro {
private final XhtmlContent xhtmlUtils;
public MyConfluenceMacro(XhtmlContent xhtmlUtils)
{
    this.xhtmlUtils = xhtmlUtils;   
}
public String execute(Map<String, String> parameters, String bodyContent,
        ConversionContext conversionContext) throws MacroExecutionException {
    String body = conversionContext.getEntity().getBodyAsString();
    final List<MacroDefinition> macros = new ArrayList<MacroDefinition>();
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.println("Part 1");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    try {
        xhtmlUtils.handleMacroDefinitions(body, conversionContext,
                new MacroDefinitionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MacroDefinition macroDefinition) {
                        macros.add(macroDefinition);
                        System.out.println("===============================================");
                        System.out.println("Part 2");
                        System.out.println("===============================================");
                    }
                });
    } catch (XhtmlException e) {
        throw new MacroExecutionException(e);
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<p>");
    if (!macros.isEmpty()) {
        builder.append("<table width=\"50%\">");
        builder.append("<tr><th>Macro Name</th><th>Has Body?</th></tr>");
        for (MacroDefinition defn : macros) {
            System.out.println("===============================================");
            System.out.println("Part 3");
            System.out.println("===============================================");
            builder.append("<tr>");
            builder.append("<td>").append(defn.getName())
                    .append("</td><td>").append(defn.hasBody())
                    .append("</td>");
            builder.append("</tr>");
        }
        builder.append("</table>");
    }
    else
    {
        builder.append("you´ve done building yourself a macro! Nice Worku! Work Work!");
        System.out.println("===============================================");
        System.out.println("Part 4");
        System.out.println("===============================================");
    }
    builder.append("</p>");
    return builder.toString();
}
@Override
public BodyType getBodyType() {
    return BodyType.NONE;
}
@Override
public OutputType getOutputType() {
    return OutputType.BLOCK;
}
}
```

and atlassian-plugin.xml:

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${atlassian.plugin.key}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
<plugin-info>
    <description>${project.description}</description>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
</plugin-info>
<xhtml-macro name="company-confluence-macro" class="com.company.confluence.plugin.MyConfluenceMacro" key="my-macro">
    <parameters/>
</xhtml-macro>
<!-- add our i18n resource -->
<resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="company-confluence-macro"/>
</atlassian-plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial is deprecated, if someone have problems with creating confluence macro:

> -atlas-create-confluence-macro
>
> -delete *test* folder
>
> -atlas-mvn eclispe:eclipse
>
> -import project to your eclipse workspace
>
> -create macro class like in tutorial.(this should be your only class on this stage, delete others)
>
> -add this to your  atlassian-plugin.xml behind  *i18n resource* line.
>
> (modify "class=" variable for your project)

```
<xhtml-macro name="PLUGIN" class="com.project.xxx.mymacro" key="mymacro" icon="/download/resources/${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}/images/pluginIcon.png">
    <category name="external-content"/> 
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="link" type="string" required="true"/>
    </parameters>
    <description>Inserts a calendar for the week into the current page</description>
    </xhtml-macro>
```

> -atlas-package
>
> -atlas-run
>
> -atlas-install-plugin

That worked for me on atlas-6.2.6, i know this question is very old but there are still problems with it. And many anwsers are not clear or already deprecated...